# QtChart включить сглаживание графика

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

Подскажите как в QtСhart сгладить график

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

foreach (int key, chart_data[0].get_spectra_data().keys() )
{
    *series << QPoint( key, chart_data[0].get_spectra_data().value( key ) );
}

QChart *chart;
chart = new QChart();
chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

chartView = new QChartView();
chartView->setChart( chart );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]